# Adding custom response header using ModifyResponse in golang gives unpredictable result

Tags: http, go, http-headers, reverse-proxy

The goal was to add customer headers to the reverse proxy. Found a way to do it using ModifyResponse. Added 3 response headers mentioned below.

Golang version

go version go1.8 linux/amd64

```
package middleware

import (
    "context"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
    "time"

    "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
    "github.com/felixge/httpsnoop"
)

var customHeader1 string
var customHeader2 string
var customHeader3 string

func UpdateResponse(r *http.Response) error {

    r.Header.Set("Custom-Header1", customHeader1)
    r.Header.Set("Custom-Header2", customHeader2)
    r.Header.Set("Custom-Header3", customHeader3)
    return nil
}

func ReverseProxy(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, serverURL *url.URL, path string) {
    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(serverURL)

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 65*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    go func() {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            Log.Error(ctx.Err()) // prints "context deadline exceeded"
            return
        }
    }()

    proxy.Director = func(req *http.Request) {
        targetQuery := r.URL.RawQuery
        req.Host = serverURL.Host
        req.URL.Scheme = serverURL.Scheme
        req.URL.Host = serverURL.Host
        req.URL.Path = path
        req.URL.RawQuery = targetQuery //+ "&" + req.URL.RawQuery
        if _, ok := req.Header["User-Agent"]; !ok {
            req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "")
        }
    }
    // Printing it out in log
    CustomHeader1 = r.Header.Get("Custom-Header1")
    CustomHeader2 = r.Header.Get("Custom-Header2")
    CustomHeader3 = r.Header.Get("Custom-Header3")
    var Uid string
    Uid = r.Header.Get("Resource-Owner-Uid")
    Log.Printf("---daily--- %s =-= %s", CustomHeader1, Uid)
    Log.Printf("---before daily--- %s =-= %s", CustomHeader3, Uid)

    proxy.ModifyResponse = UpdateResponse

    Log.Printf("---after-daily--- %s =-= %s", CustomHeader1, Uid)
    Log.Printf("---after-daily--- %s =-= %s", CustomHeader3, Uid)
    //If Server have already path with it.
    if len(serverURL.Path) > 0 {
        path = serverURL.Path + path
    }
    r.URL.Path = path

    Log.Formatter = &logrus.JSONFormatter{}
    r = r.WithContext(ctx)
    m := httpsnoop.CaptureMetrics(proxy, w, r)
    Log.Printf(
        "host=%s remoteaddr=%s url=%s rawquery=%s Method=%s URL=%s  resourceOwnerID=%s resourceOwnerType=%s resourceOwnerUID=%s (StatusCode=%d duration=%s written=%d) customheader1=%s customerheader3=%s respcustomheader1=%s respcustomheader3=%s",
        r.Host,
        r.RemoteAddr,
        r.URL.Path,
        r.URL.RawQuery,
        r.Method,
        r.URL,
        r.Header["Resource-Owner-Id"],
        r.Header["Resource-Owner-Type"],
        r.Header["Resource-Owner-Uid"],
        m.Code,
        m.Duration,
        m.Written,
        r.Header["Custom-Header1"],
        r.Header["Custom-Header3"],
        w.Header().Get("Custom-Header1"),
        w.Header().Get("Custom-Header3"),
    )
}

// Log 
{"level":"info","msg":"---daily--- false =-= uid","time":""}
{"level":"info","msg":"---daily --- false =-= uid","time":""}
{"level":"info","msg":"---after-daily--- false =-= uid","time":""}
{"level":"info","msg":"---after-daily --- false =-= uid","time":""}
time="" level=info msg="host= remoteaddr= url= rawquery= Method=POST URL=  resourceOwnerID=[] resourceOwnerType=[] resourceOwnerUID=[] (StatusCode=200 duration=26.098272ms written=78) customheader1=[false] customheader3=[false] respcustomheader1=false respcustomheader3=true"

Expected was respcustomheader3= false
```

As you can see in the log, custom printed logs are false for the same but printed inside the Log.Printf is true. This value is set in the backend server which is sent back to reverse-proxy in response header and customheader1 is false in backend servers too. Even same data i'm storing in DB is also false from where im reading it.
If I retry again the respcustomheader3 is false.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Is my approach correct any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: You create and configure your proxy but you never use it at any point in the quoted code. You even create a wrapped handler with it using `httpsnoop` and you never use that either. So, since it isn't being used, it has no opportunity to do anything to the request. Also your context handling is inherently broken; you have a goroutine waiting for context cancellation, which it responds to by returning *from the goroutine* - effectively it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Adrian, the above code, is my core logic of reverse proxy. I'm calling it from another controller middleware.ReverseProxy(w, r, target, requestPath).  
Will look into goroutine waiting for context cancellation too. Thanks for your input

Comment: It doesn't matter what you're calling it from. You don't use or return the proxy. You create it and then it gets discarded. So anything you expect the proxy to do won't happen.